# how to make 2x2 image grid CSS

Tags: css, grid, photo

I am a journalism student and I cannot figure out to do the CSS for a working 2x2 image grid, at first the images were in a row now they are very stretched out in a column. Could someone please help me figure out how to do this? [(photo of my code)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QveyM.png)

```
/* Work Layout */
.work div {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: wrap;
  width: 150px;
  height: 300px;
}
.img {
  "images/benbball.jpg"
  width: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do is set up a container to hold all of your images, and set `float: left` and `width: 50%` on your child `img` selector. As the `width` is set to `50%`, only two will be able to fit per row, and the next two will drop to the next row.

This can be seen in the following:

```css
.container img {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50" />
</div>
```

If you want space between the images, you'll need to give each individual `<img>` a parental containing element to set the `float: left` and `width: 50%` on, with an additional constrained `width` and optional `margin` on the child `<img>`. For best effect, this would be a calculation-driven width which is `100%` minus the margins:

```css
.container .image {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.container img {
  width: calc(100% - (20px * 2));
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50" />
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50" />
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50" />
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Or, if you want to use flexbox, you'll want to set `display: flex` and `flex-wrap: wrap` on the container:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container .image {
  width: 50%;
}

.container img {
  width: calc(100% - (20px * 2));
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50" />
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50" />
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50" />
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50" />
  </div>
</div>
```

With flexbox, you won't need `float: left`.

Answer (score 2):

CSS Grid

```
.wrapper {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, [col-start] 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}


<div class="grid">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50" />
</div>
```